# Hitting performance issues with jboss drools engine. creating KnowledgeBase object for every call/request is an issue?

Tags: drools

Hitting performance issues with jboss drools engine.

below is the sample code.

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory
                .newKnowledgeBuilder();
        for (RuleDO ruleDO : ruleDOs) {
            String drool = ruleDO.getDrool();
            Reader reader = new StringReader(drool);
            kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newReaderResource(reader),
                    ResourceType.DRL);
        }

        KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
        Notification notification = new Notification();

        StatelessKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase
                .newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
        ksession.setGlobal("notification", notification);
        ksession.execute(device);
```

I took the thread dump while doing the performance testing and found more time spent on below two lines.

```
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newReaderResource(reader), ResourceType.DRL);
```

And

```
KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
```

creating KnowledgeBase object for every call/request is an issue ?

should i cache KnowledgeBase in my application ?

Answer (score 1):

The answers are "yes", and "yes".

Moreover, you are creating the KnowledgeBase in a rather circumstantial way, adding one rule after the other. A much faster way would be to collect the strings into a single string and add this as a whole.

Note that the technique for serializing a compiled KnowledgeBase for repeated deserialization is well documented in the Drools Expert manual.

Also, the title of your question seems to indicate that your rule-based application expects repeated independent requests, and this may be advantageously handled by sessions being created independently from the same KnowledgeBase object.